# SQL how to swap two specific values from a column

Tags: sql

Hi so my question is exactly as it sounds.

I need to swap two values from the column to another value, I know doing

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET COLUMN_1 = VALUE
WHERE CONDITION
```

Works but my problem is that I need to also swap another value to that existing value. In the table below I need to swap baker and baxter, so where ever baxter is, I need it to be baker and where there is baker I need it to be baxter.

```
ARTISTNAME 

BILL
BAKER
JOHN
BAKER
BAXTER
MARY
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `case`:

```
update t
    set col = (case when col = 'Baker' then 'Baxter' else 'Baker' end)
    where col in ('Baker', 'Baxter');
```